# How do I show foreground notifications?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending notifications from Firebase cloud messaging. The background notification works fine, but I can't find something that worked in the foreground for me.

I want to display the notification when the app is open same as when the app is in background: with the system notification sound and the same banner display at the top of screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control this on iOS

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(badge: true, alert: true, sound: true);
```

> package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart
>
> Sets the presentation options for Apple notifications when received in
> the foreground.
>
> By default, on Apple devices notification messages are only shown when
> the application is in the background or terminated. Calling this
> method updates these options to allow customizing notification
> presentation behaviour whilst the application is in the foreground.
>
> Important: The requested permissions and those set by the user take
> priority over these settings.
>
> [alert] Causes a notification message to display in the foreground,
> overlaying the current application (heads up mode). [badge] The
> application badge count will be updated if the application is in the
> foreground. [sound] The device will trigger a sound if the application
> is in the foreground. If all arguments are false or are omitted, a
> notification will not be displayed in the foreground, however you will
> still receive events relating to the notification.

Comment: What about on android .? Its foreground notifications are also not working... Does this work for both  ??

Comment: On android, that is not possible currently. All messages received while the app is in the foreground, do not display a notification as in the backgroud. However, the data and logic are still handled. As per the documentation, foreground messages run in a seperate isolate from your app's UI, and therefore to make any changes to UI, you need to implement such logic manually. If you test printing out the notification data in the console, you will see that it is being handled, and in the form of `foregroundMessage`, but without a notification sound or overlaying display banner.

Comment: Thanks Huthaifa,, I have made changes to UI when the app is in foreground in my app... But there's a part of my app that i am using web view... foreground notification is working fine there too but as i am showing a pop up, it is displayed behind the webview.(which appears when i hot restart the app).. is there any way around showing that on top of web view.?

Comment: it does not work for `flutter version 2.0.4` and `firebase_messaging version 9.1.3`